# La question sur « mal- » vs. « mé- »

Tags: sens, préfixes

Quelle est la différence sémantique entre ces deux préfixes négatifs ?

Comment: Je pense qu'il n'y a pas de différence sémantique, mais juste une différence de formation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il est difficile de trouver une différence sémantique car les deux préfixes ne sont quasiment jamais en concurrence.

Mal-/mau- vient du Latin *malus* alors que mé-/més vient selon la plupart des sources du francique *missi* qui introduit une forme négative ou péjorative  (cf. anglais *mis-*)

Le seul doublon que j'ai trouvé est:

> - médire
> - maudire

Dans ce cas précis, il ne fait pas de doute que « maudire » est plus intense que « médire ».

Comment: C'est intéressant, ça, que _mal-_ et _mau-_ soient une variation sur le même préfixe! _Malgré_ et _maugréer_ seraient donc deux variantes d'une même construction? C'est vraiment extraordinaire de voir combien leurs significations se sont éloignées l'une de l'autre!

Comment: @Feelew Oui, « maugréer » pouvait s'écrire *malgréer* en ancien français et « malgré nous» *maugré nostre*…

Answer (score 0):

Je pense que 'mé' est juste pour proposer l'inverse du mot.
'Mal' montre l'inverse mais ajoute un côté négatif, mauvais.